# How to get data out of a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I want to make a summation of the collected data from a while loop because I want to calculate Youtube video duration to divide them into days. I want to make something which collects the final answer from each loop and makes a summation process of them. How can I do that?

My code is:

```
while True:
    def youtube_calculater(x):
        return x * 60

    a = youtube_calculater(float(input("enter minutes: ")))

    def sum_operation(y):
        return a + y

    b = sum_operation(float(input("enter seconds: ")))

    def final_operation(n):
        return n / 60

    s = final_operation(b)
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store every calculated `s` inside a list (I named it `s_list` in the example) and then use `sum()` to calculate the sum of all the entries.

```
s_list = []

while True:
    def youtube_calculater(x):
        return x * 60

    a = youtube_calculater(float(input("enter minutes: ")))

    def sum_operation(y):
        return a + y

    b = sum_operation(float(input("enter seconds: ")))

    def final_operation(n):
        return n / 60

    s = final_operation(b)
    s_list.append(s)
    print(s)
    print(sum(s_list))
```

If you dont care about every entry in the list. You can just create a variable `sum_s` the same way and always add `s` to the sum using `sum_s += s`.